# Android automatic pairing with devices through bluetooth

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and i searched but i didn't find the solution. Is there any way to connect with other device automatically through bluetooth. 
For instance i can save the registered device's **MAC id** on my server. And i have other device which have a list of all registered MAC ids. So i want to auto accept data from those registered devices.
I read the bluetooth chatting example but there also it ask for pairing. Is there any way to auto accept data from specific MAC ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to **paired** devices, but you, for security reasons, cannot silently pair.

Comment: Marcin there is no way to save registered MAC addresses in phone?